# When is evolutionary algorithm useless?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Is there any specific reasons why the evolutionary algorithm is an inappropriate method to use when searching for a key to decrypt a coded message. When there are billions of wrong answers and only one right answer.

Comment: "Useless" and "inappropriate" in what sense? What is known about the message? Can anything be learned from the data about this problem (if not, then the question is off-topic in here and it has obvious answer). Your question at this form in too broad, not really clear and so unanswerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a specific reason.

Many optimization algorithms, such as hill climbing, rely on the idea that when you change the proposed solution a little bit, the function you are trying to optimize (the fitness function in the case of an evolutionary algorithm) also changes a little bit. These algorithms are based on the idea of perturbing the best solution you have already found in order to obtain a better one. (In the case of an evolutionary algorithm, this would correspond to mutation. You also have recombination, in which you leap to a different part of the solution space in the hope of getting a big improvement in fitness.)

For example, think about the [boxcar2d](http://boxcar2d.com/) example of a genetic algorithm in action. Making a slight change to the car will probably mean only a slight increase or decrease in its performance.

For the problem in which you are searching for a specific key with no further information (say it was just a random string of characters) you don't have the same sort of fitness function; in this case, every string which is not a key is equally bad, so methods which rely on making small steps are useless. Instead of being a smoothly-varying landscape, the fitness function is completely flat except for one peak somewhere, and there is no better method for finding that peak than guessing at random.